# Using HTML tag to carry customized attributes

Tags: jquery

I need to make an ajax call to retrieve a list of items, each item will become an HTML element such as `<li/>` by using jQuery's `.html();` then a click on the `<li/>` will trigger a function with the data about the item.

The question is what is a better strategy to associate item data with the `<li/>`.

Currently I'm trying to make the item data a customized attribute to `<li/>`.

For example I'll create it as `<li myattr='itemData'>itemDisplayStr </li>`. However I cannot get the data back in click event, as:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    alert(this.myattr);
    alert(this.attr('myattr'));
    alert(this.attributes['myattr']);
});
```

None of above works.

Can anyone give me some clues?
Thanks

Comment: You're calling `this.attr('myattr')` but said you set it as `itemDisplayStr`. I assume this is just quickly written sample code? try `$(this).attr('itemDisplayStr);`

Comment: @MetalFrog. yes, he needs `$(this)` see the docs I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`this` isn't a `jQuery object`. Surround it with `$()` => `$(this)` to create jQuery object:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('myattr'));
});
```

**docs**

> Within the handler, the keyword this refers to the DOM element to which the handler is bound. To make use of the element in jQuery, it can be passed to the normal $()

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

`alert($(this).attr('myattr'))` ?

Comment: Thanks for the light-fast answers. And the solution is just as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

did you explore [jquery data](http://api.jquery.com/data/)?

```
$('li').data('foo', 52);
$('li').data('bar', { myType: 'test', count: 40 });

$('li').data('foo'); // 52
$('li').data(); // {foo: 52, bar: { myType: 'test', count: 40 }}
```

have fun with JSON

**edit**
for what its worth each li wouldnt need its own id if you did something like

```
ul.append( $("<li>" + label + "</li>").data("foo", "bar") );
```

Comment: Didn't know about .data(). I'll remember to use it in the future. But for this one I need to use each &lt;lt/> individually, I may need to dynamically create an id for each item, if using .data().

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use jQuery to use the `attr()` function: `$()`.

```
$(this).attr('myattr');
```

Comment: Thanks for the light-fast answers. And the solution is just as simple as that.